# Using Flask to embed a local HTML page

Tags: python-3.x, flask, folium

So I am using this cool plugin called Folium which creates maps. The map gets created as a .html and every time you update the map it regenerates the html. So in order to display the map and my navbar and other stuff on the same page I think I would need to put map.html inside an iframe cage where it can refresh itself at will.

The map gets created thus:

```
map1 = folium.Map(location=[45.5, -73.61], width="100%", height="100%")
map1.save('./maps/map.html')
```

And I have tried iframeing it thus:

```
<iframe src="/maps/map.html"></iframe>
```

But I get `404 error`

Someone yesterday suggested that I build an endpoint for it like this:

```
@app.route('/http://127.0.0.1:4995/maps/map')
def show_map():
return flask.send_file('/maps/map.html')
```

But I keep getting 404 error

Answer (score 8):

You have your route defined incorrectly. As you had it written, you defined the route for `http://yourserver/http://127.0.0.1:4995/maps/map` when instead what I think you wanted was `http://yourserver/maps/map.html`. To achieve this, you will want to use the following

```
@app.route('/maps/map.html')
def show_map():
    return flask.send_file('/maps/map.html')
```

Flask will automatically prepend your server's address (`http://127.0.0.1:4995`) to the beginning of any route that you define.

Also, in the template for your HTML, I would use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) to get the URL for the map to avoid changes in your routes requiring changes to your templates.

```
<iframe src="{{ url_for('show_map') }}"></iframe>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the info. however I still can't get it to work. I have first endpoint `@app.route('/')` which ends with `return render_template('index.html')`, then another endpoint `@app.route('/data/map.html')` with `return send_file('data/plot.html')`. However if I load the page I get `127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2018 15:03:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2018 15:03:48] "GET /data/plot.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: ah it worked adding `static_folder='data'`to the `Flask(...)` initialization!

Comment: @lorenzori I have a similar error but I'm trying to embed the folium map into my index.html. Currently the html page works fine on its own but under flask's render_template('index.html') it doesn't. Any ideas?